# Different functions?

Tags: c++, overriding, signature, virtual-functions, default-arguments

So here is code sample. The task was to give output that this code will print out. Is it 2 different functions? What happens with vtable in B class then?
Does it just store 2 pointers on 2 different functions with same name?

```
#include<iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class A
{
public:
    A()
    {
        init();
    }
    virtual void init(bool a = true)
    {
        if(a)
            cout << "A" << endl;
    }
};
class B :public A
{
public:
    virtual void init()
    {
        cout << "B" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    A* a = &b;
    a->init();
    a->init(true);
    system("pause");
}
```

Couldn't really find where to read about this case. Could you mates explain or give a link to some source if you've seen this case?

Comment: Try compiling it with warnings enabled - you should get at least one helpful warning which will give you some insight...

Comment: @PaulR GCC [remains silent](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4ea14d3bb087bfa0).

Comment: Oh, clang is evidently more helpful then... `<stdin>:21:18: warning: 'B::init' hides overloaded virtual function [-Woverloaded-virtual]
    virtual void init()
                 ^
<stdin>:12:18: note: hidden overloaded virtual function 'A::init' declared here: different number of parameters (1 vs 0)
    virtual void init(bool a = true)`

Comment: This is the reason for `override`.

Comment: FWIW MSVC++ also generates a warning. Neither gcc or ICC do though.

Comment: Every function you write is different from others. The real question is «when I make a call, which one is selected?»

Comment: Don't use the silly `system("pause");` if you want to keep the window open. Use "Start Without Debugging" (Ctrl+F5) instead.

Comment: @PaulR gcc will warn if you explicitly add the `-Woverloaded-virtual` switch which you have shown in the clang warning message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They were already two different functions (overriding doesn't change that), but because they have a different signature, the one in `B` does *not* override the one in `A`.

Remember, the name of a function is only part of its identity! Its parameter list matters too.

If you'd put the `override` keyword on `B::init()` then your program would have failed to compile because `B::init()` doesn't actually override anything (there is no `init()`, virtual or otherwise, in its base).

Nothing really "happens" with the vtable that wouldn't also have happened if the two functions literally had different names, like `A::init(bool)` and `B::urgleburgleboop()`.

Note that, quite aside from `virtual` and polymorphism and overriding, `B::init()` also "hides" `A::init(bool)` for normal overload resolution (thanks, C++!), and because of this Clang will warn on your code.

As for where you can read about it, [your C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/560648) would be a good start. :)

Comment: Good answer, I was writing one using `nm` and showing that the mangled symbols are different for the two methods signatures but the theory is enough there.